# How do I send payload in superagent

Tags: node.js, request, payload, superagent

I am not sure how to send payload using superagent, does anyone know that can reply with how to do it under here?

my guess would be:

```
.payload({
    "key": "value"
    "key2": "value2"
})


Please Help! :)
```

Comment: Use `.send({ name: 'Manny', species: 'cat' })`  to send a JSON post body